# How to find move constructors in codebase using grep or an IDE?

Tags: c++, move-constructor

I want to find move constructors in codebase of a large c++ project. Simply grepping for "&&" doesn't work, because it matches a lot of 'logical and' operators.

Any way to grep more precisely for move constructors?

Any way to search for move constructors using Visual Studio (on Windows) or XCode (on Mac)?

Comment: Use Clang and dump the AST? (Or even clang-query?)

Comment: @KerrekSB, would be interesting to see a sample, I've asked another question specifically about Clang tools now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706053/how-to-find-move-constructors-in-codebase-using-clang-ast-tools

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a job for **regular expressions**. In **Visual Studio**, press **ctrl+F**. In the search pop-up window, activate the option "**Use regular expressions**" (or press **alt+E**, when the search line is active). Then type the following expression:

```
\b\w+\s*[\(]\s*(const)*\s*(volatile)*\s*\w+\s*[&][&]\s*[\)]
```

It will find any string of the form:

```
class_name(class_name&&)
class_name(const class_name&&)
class_name(volatile class_name&&)
class_name(const volatile class_name&&)
```

as specified in:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor

The expression works also if there is any number of whitespaces between class_name, parentheses and keywords like const etc.

If you want it to work also for named variables, e.g.:

```
class_name(class_name&& variable_name)
```

it's enough to modify it slightly:

```
\b(\w+)\s*[\(]\s*(const)*\s*(volatile)*\s*\1\s*[&][&]\s*\w*\s*[\)]
```

EDIT: As an answer to the OP's request, I've modified the above regex in such a way that it uses backreference now. The '\1' means "Find the same expression that was captured by the first expression grouped in parentheses" - the first such expression is (\w+), which is the first '**class_name**' in the examplary move constructors above. This ensures that there is the same string on both sides of this guy: '('. To sum it up: one additional pair of parentheses, '\1' and magic happens.

Interesting thing is that Microsoft doesn't mention that VS supports backreferences.

More information about regular expressions in Visual Studio can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @user3564091! :)  I do need the named parameters too, but unfortunately the second regex matches logical "and" and there are too many of them. Can the regex check that the class_name token before and after the ( is the same? (Is that sort of regexes supported by VS?)

Comment: I modified the second regex to use backreference, worked liked a charm in VS 2013: \b(\w+)\s*[\(]\s*(const)*\s*(volatile)*\s*(\1)\s*[&][&]\s*\w*\s*[\)]

Comment: Oh, I've just done the same and updated the answer :D

Comment: BTW, I think tools like grep on Mac use the same regex format, so chances are you don't have to change anything and may use this regex as a parameter for grep if you need.

Comment: Reminds me of the old phrase. If you use regular expressions to solve a problem. You now have twice as many problems.

Comment: @LokiAstari, I'm pragmatic, I don't know of any simpler solution :)

Comment: I've cleaned up the regex a little bit, removed unnecessary captures and square brackets, I doubt cv-qualifier are so useful there, but I kept them anyway, this works for my codebase:  \b(\w+)\s*\(\s*(?:const)?\s*(?:volatile)?\s*\1\s*&&\s*\w*\s*\)

Comment: A matter of taste I guess :) For me it's easier to read if some of the chars are in square brackets. Also, I think it's safer to escape parentheses as they might be interpreted incorectly. This time VS interprets them OK, but I guess it might induce error in some other context as they may be read as grouping parentheses in the expression instead of ordinary chars to be searched.